# react router's location state becomes undefined on change of route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to store `url query`  as a state on location.

```
~   history.push({
+     ...history.location,
+     search: query.toString(),
+     state: {
+       myState: query.toString(),
+     },
+   })
```

I suspect get state when a route change, but `state` become `undefined` when I back from other route.

Answer (score 7):

This is how `state` (which comes from the History API) works. State is attached to a location in a session and does not exist (or rather, is `null`) when you navigate directly to a page.

In general, I would not recommend using location.state for passing anything but temporary data (like a redirect location). If you need data attached to a location I would recommend using either path params or search params and having a store that you can lookup that data from.

```
// path params
{ pathname: `/path/name/${SOME_ID}` }
// search params
{ search: `?someID=${SOME_ID}` }
```

If you really want to use location.state, your route will need to have some sort of backup plan for using some default value when location.state is null.

Answer (score 1):

Its the second argument in `history.push(path, [state])`

`history.push("path/you/want/to/push/to", { state: myState: query.toString() })`

You can look for the state from `location.state`

**Note:** Also the state will **not** be available in other routes. Each route has its own state which is inaccessible by other routes.

Its stated in the docs [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/location.md)

> Normally you just use a string, but if you need to add some "location
>   state" that will be available whenever the app returns to that
>   specific location, you can use a location object instead. This is
>   useful if you want to branch UI based on navigation history instead of
>   just paths (like modals).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the pathname. you should write the exact url to send state.

target url=`/page1/page2/page3/`

```
 const path = '/page1/page2/page3';
 history.push({ pathname: `${path}`, state: {item: myItem}}); //state will be undefined
```

```
 const path = '/page1/page2/page3/';
 history.push({ pathname: `${path}`, state: {item: myItem}); //state will be {item: myItem}
```