# React cannot read properties of array undefined while using use location hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, react-redux

I am trying to pass some data from one page to the other in react using the useNavigate and useLocation hook.The data is transferring fine and i am recieving it in the next component as shown below:

```
// sending component
   const handleNavigate = () => {
   navigate('/updateBlogPost', { state: { blogPost } });
};

//recieving component
const location = useLocation();
const [title, setTitle] = useState(location.state.blogPost.title);
const [description, setDescription] = useState(location.state.blogPost.description);
const [categories, setCategories] = useState(location.state.blogPost.categories);
const [content, setContent] = useState(location.state.blogPost.content);
```

Now I am facing the problem with the category array because it becomes undefined when the page first renders and i get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

I can get rid of the error using optional chaining but how to get the data of the array when it is available.
I tried setting it in the use effect but it does not seems to work can any one suggest some better way?

Comment: You have a typo in 3rd useState function: "ocation" instead of "location":
`const [description, setDescription] = useState(ocation.state.blogPost.description);`

Comment: yes, but it is not the main problem. the problem is with the category array

Comment: Look for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56632537/6087422)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use useEffect to get data when its available based on dependencies of "location" changes everytime it will fire it after every completed render.

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if(location.state.blogPost.categories)
     setCategories(location.state.blogPost.categories)
},[location])
```

Comment: I have already tried this before. Again tried it on your recommendation but the states don't seem to be changing and the array remains to be undefined. I have tried putting both location and location.state.blogPost.categories in the dependency array but its not working.

Comment: change code in "if" condition to   `if(location?.state?.blogPost?.categories)`

if not then try   `if(location?.state?.blogPost?.categories && location?.state?.blogPost?.categories!==undefined )`